# Bolding Text with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Here's the cell formula I'm using:

```
="Charge: "&(UPPER(AG343))&"    "&" Charging Staff: "&(AH343)&"    "&" Charging Staff: "&(AI343)&"    "&" CAP_ID: "&(AJ343)
```

Is there a way in VBA to recognize that a value is being pulled into `Cell "A"` from a reference to `Cell "B"` and to make the text representation of the reference from `Cell "B"` in `Cell "A"` bold?

I've seen posts on this subject on the limitations of Excel functions to manipulate text. I don't understand why I can use the `UPPER` function on the results of a cell reference or on text in general in a cell formula, but not be allowed to bold text in a formula.

Is there a way in VBA to apply the Bold property to text in a cell?

Is there a way to use the `"ActiveCell.Characters"` property to the cell references to get bolded text?

Comment: The best you can do is format the cell with the formula as bold. You can't use the cell's `Characters` collection on a cel lwith a formula, and the formula itself can't control formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the formula, but with vba.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String
    Dim k1 As Integer, k2 As Integer, k3 As Integer
    Set rng = ActiveCell

    s1 = Range("AH343")
    s2 = Range("AI343")
    s3 = Range("Aj343")

    s = "Charging Staff: " & s1 & "    " & " Charging Staff: " & s2 & "    " & " CAP_ID: " & s3

    k1 = InStr(s, s1)
    k2 = InStr(s, s2)
    k3 = InStr(s, s3)
    rng = s
    With rng
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Characters(k1, Len(s1)).Font.Bold = True
        .Characters(k2, Len(s2)).Font.Bold = True
        .Characters(k3, Len(s3)).Font.Bold = True
    End With
End Sub
```

This is the same code using the for statement.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim vS As Variant, vK()
    Dim i As Integer
    Set rng = ActiveCell

    vS = Range("Ah343").Resize(1, 3)

    s = "Charging Staff: " & vS(1, 1) & "    " & " Charging Staff: " & vS(1, 2) & "    " & " CAP_ID: " & vS(1, 3)

    For i = 1 To UBound(vS, 2)
        ReDim Preserve vK(1 To i)
        vK(i) = InStr(s, vS(1, i))
    Next i
    rng = s
    With rng
        .Font.Bold = False
        For i = 1 To 3
            .Characters(vK(i), Len(vS(1, i))).Font.Bold = True
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen, Thanks.

Comment: How do I answer the solution answered my question.  I haven't tested it yet, but this seems to address my question perfectly.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again for this solution works like a charm.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Aaron, If this works, would you accept your question?